# export jar file with its own import

Tags: java, import, jar, export

I import some external jar files in my code.....now I want to export all my code into one .jar file as library and use in other project

In new project Should I import that jar files again??
How can I export just one jar file?
Is this work correct?

```
package dactivemq;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
public class Producer {....
.....
```

Comment: what build tool and/or IDE are you using ?

Comment: I'm using eclipse just

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a build tool to make this easier? You can make it a maven project and use maven assembly plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies.

Usage of maven assembly plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Thank you so much...just I don't know this work is correct...I means combine all jars in one build

Comment: No problem..if you want a stand alone jar, it would have to an uber jar with all the dependencies packaged together with it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Maven to resolve dependencies. To create a single Jar with all you need I use the maven-assembly-plugin configured like that:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>it.xxx.Launcher</mainClass>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```